# Full collection scan with $NOT, using index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

We have a data structure in which we have an array (in actuality the array is of subdocuments):

```
{ "someField" : ["value1", "value2"]}
```

We have constructing a query like this:

```
db.collection.find({"someField":{ 
                       $in :["value1", "blah"], 
                       $not : { $in : ["value2"]}}})
```

NOTE: I know we don't need the second `in` for a single value but we need to support multiples.

When have an index on `someField`. If you just query on `in` and do an explain, the `indexBounds` looks like:

```
  "indexBounds": {"someField:[["value1","value1"], ["blah", "blah"]]}
```

This works great with efficient use of the index. When you run the query if the `in` and the `not in` we had hoped it would use the same bounds and then test the scanned objects for the not condition. Instead the `indexBounds` looks like this:

```
  "indexBounds": {"someField:[[{"$minElement":1}, "value2"], [value2 : {"$maxElement":1}]]}
```

This results is scanning the entire collection.

Are we doing something wrong? Is there some other way to constructor this query.

Currently the only solution we can up with was to do an aggregate with multiple match statements (one with the inclusive portion first, then the exclusive portion). Funny thing about that is that if you do `{match, match}` in an aggregate, they are combined and you end up with the same result so we had to do `{match, project, match}` to make each match distinct so that the first would use the index as desired.

*NOTE: I cannot copy / paste from my work system so I cannot copy the entire explain.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a proper index and are constructing the query in the natural and correct way. You can use `$nin` instead of `$not` with `$in`, but it doesn't change index selection. This is an instance where [SERVER-12281](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12281) would be helpful, but that feature hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `$nin` and `12281`. It looks like `12281` is exactly the reason. Bummer. Is the suggested aggregate an appropriate way to get around this?